# Can the Gini coefficient be meaningfully applied to integer partitions?

Tags: number-theory

Can the Gini coefficient be meaningfully applied to integer partitions?

Since it is a measure of statistical dispersion, it seems like it might be relevant.

Comment: How could it *not* apply?

Comment: I mean, can it be milked to give some additional information about integer partitions - eg "For integer partitions whose Gini coefficient is > 0.8, the formula for the number of integer partition is..."  :)

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to get an intuition for what high Gini coefficient means for partitions. The first one to break .7, by the way, is the partition of 38 (31, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1). I _think_ the first to break .8 is the partition of 90 consisting of 82 and eight 1s.